# $M$ and $N$ flat, then $M\otimes N$ flat

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

I want to show that if $M$ and $N$ are flat $R$-modules, then $M\otimes_R N$ is flat.

By flat we mean that if $0\to A\to B$ is exact, then $0\to A\otimes_RM\to B\otimes_RM$ is exact.

I am assuming that I want to use the fact that tensor products are associative, i.e. $A\otimes_R (M\otimes_R N) \cong (A\otimes_R M)\otimes_R N$ and then somehow use that $M$ is flat, but I have no idea how to work with the maps that I need.

Comment: Presumably you meant to write $\otimes$ rather than $\oplus$ in your associativity statement? But perhaps distributivity of the tensor product with the direct sum is more useful.

Comment: That is correct, my mistake. I usually define a tensor command to avoid that issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We start with
$$
0\to A\to B
$$
exact. Since $M$ is flat, by definition we have that
$$
0\to A\otimes M\to B\otimes M
$$
is exact. Then, since $N$ is flat, 
$$
0\to(A\otimes M)\otimes N\to (B\otimes M)\otimes N
$$
is exact. Now use the associativity, and you're done.

Comment: Hmm...not sure why I didn't think of that. One question: How do we know $A\otimes M$ and $B\otimes M$ are $R$-modules. Or more generally, when do we get modules from tensor products, rather than just abelian groups?

Comment: @Ziyerx If $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules, then $M\otimes_R N$ is always an $R$-module (at least for $R$ commutative, there are some right and left multiplication subtleties that I don't remember for non-commutative $R$).